# createjs ipad low performance

Tags: javascript, ios, html, canvas

the situation is as follows: there is an HTML5 game. The game is quite heavy in terms of the javascript code, graphics and sounds – approximately 30 MB. All the animation is created by means of createjs. In the game I use 2 canvases one over the other; the control buttons are between the canvases (the buttons are created by means of the standard button elements).

One canvas is the main one and most of the animation is implemented on this canvas; the second canvas is used when it is necessary to show the animation over the control buttons. Initially, the size of each canvas was 970px x 740px. All the animation worked perfectly in desktop browsers as well as in Chrome and FireFox in Android. However, in the mobile Safari browser the animation worked very slowly.

Then I reduced the size of the canvases by 30 % (accordingly to the graph on the sprite sheets). As a result, Safari started working more efficiently on an ipad. The animation of the lower canvas stopped hanging but only unless the extra animation was launched on the upper canvas. Then everything got slow again. I don’t apply WebGL because I have to use both bitmap and the vector graphics. Who knows how to improve the situation in this case so as to prevent the FPS from falling, could you help me, please?

There is another funny thing: if you minimize the browser and then maximize it again, the game starts working faster from time to time.

Comment: Have you tried [any of these optimizations?](https://blog.toggl.com/2013/05/6-performance-tips-for-html-canvas-and-createjs/) Your aspect ratio seems to be just barely outside of the suggested range so that may be something to consider as well.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I try to follow these tips.